# How to insert ALL items in combobox to mysql one column?

Tags: mysql, vb.net-2010

All items on my combobox should go to my database. It should be appear when the after the form1 load. My code in inserting is not working. I hope some help me

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim one As String

    conn.Open()
    query = "select * from dbgradeslip.student"
    cmd = New MySqlCommand(query, conn)
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
    While dr.Read
        Dim fn = dr.GetString("firstname") + ", "
        Dim mn = dr.GetString("middlename") + " "
        Dim ln = dr.GetString("lastname")
        one = ln.Substring(0, 1)
        two = ComboBox6.Items.Add(fn + mn + one)
    End While


    For i = 0 To ComboBox6.Items.Count
        query = "insert into student (fullname) values ('" & ComboBox6.Items.ToString & "')"
        cmd = New MySqlCommand(query, conn)
        da.SelectCommand = cmd
    Next
    conn.Close()

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call ExecuteNonQuery on the MySqlCommand to execute the query.

```
query = "insert into student (fullname) values (@fullname)"
cmd = New MySqlCommand(query, conn)    
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fullname", "")
For i = 0 To ComboBox6.Items.Count
    cmd.Parameters["@fullname"].Value = ComboBox6.Items(i).ToString()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
Next
```

Other than that you really should use a parameterized query instead of a (wrong) string concatenation. A parameterized query avoid Sql Injections and parsing problem with strings that contains quotes. Finally, to access the individual item in the Items collection you need to use an indexer.